# Linq query to filter values from a list

Tags: c#, list, linq, conditional-statements

Assume there is model named "Fruits". It has two properties

- Name (string)
- isAvailable (bool)

I have a FruitsList and it holds some values.

```
Name   isAvailable

Apple    True
Banana   False
Mango    True
```

Now I want to get the Names of the fruits which are available as a joined string, `availableFruits = "Apple|Mango"`

```
  string  availableFruits = string.Join("|", FruitsList.Where(x => x.isAvailable= true).Select(x => x.Name));
```

This is what I have done so far and it is not working. Hope someone can help.

Comment: `FruitsList.Where(x => x.isAvailable)`. You were trying to assign `isAvailable`, rather than check its value.

Comment: `string  availableFruits = string.Join("|", FruitsList.Where(x => x.isAvailable).Select(x => x.Name));`

Comment: Thank you very much @ChetanRanpariya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your code, you are using `x.isAvailable= true`, by using like this you are assigning a value to the property, which is not a valid syntax here and hence Your query won't compile, you have to use `==` instead for `=` in comparison or simply the boolean field, finally the query would be:

```
string  availableFruits = string.Join("|", FruitsList.Where(x => x.isAvailable)
                                                     .Select(x => x.Name));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected the code and now it works :)

Comment: @sandaru: happy to help you